# Accessing the value of an "em" tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How would you access the value of an `em` tag in javascript?

This is the element I'm trying to access: `<em id='tag_IS_System_Agent'></em>`

which displays: **John Smith**

I'm trying to access it via javascript:

```
document.getElementById("emailFrame").src 
= "http://www.website.org/mail.php?cid="
  +IS_ATTR_ID.value
  +"&name="+document.write("<em id=\"tag_IS_System_Agent\">&nbsp;<\/em>")
  +"&em="+email;`
```

Any idea? I know that `document.write("<em id=\"tag_IS_System_Agent\">&nbsp;<\/em>")` is wrong and I'm stumped and not sure what to do.

Comment: `document.getElementById("tag_IS_System_Agent");`

Comment: You are trying to embed a HTML element within an elements attribute list. The browser ma allow it but obviously it will not function correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By “the value of an ‘em’ tag”, you apparently mean the content of an `em` element. If the element has an `id` attribute, as in your example, you can use the `getElementById` method of `document` to access the element node in the DOM. Then you can get the content of the element, serialized as HTML, using the `innerHTML` property. Note that this will include markup for inner elements, if any. So the expression you would use would be

```
document.getElementById('tag_IS_System_Agent').innerHTML
```

Instead of `innerHTML`, you could use `textContent`, which gives you just the textual content, without any inner tags. However, this is less widely supported (e.g., not in IE 8). If there is no inner markup, the results are the same, but `innerHTML` is thus safer.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing the value based on your markup would be:

```
var myValue = document.getElementById("tag_IS_System_Agent").textContent
```

Comment: thank you! While I thought this would work, this returns `undefined`. Using innerHTML (below) worked.

Comment: My bad, I forgot that it isn't as fully supported as `innerHTML` by IE8. As soon as we can retire IE8, we should retire innerHTML as well :)