# Accessing content of an <em> tag for a website scraper using JS

Tags: javascript, cheerio

I am new to JavaScript and trying to create a website scraper which collects certain odds from betting sites. The current website I am trying to get the odds from has their odds in  tags and I cannot seem to access the data inside. Here is the short program below:

```html
var request = require('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio')
    price = [];

request('https://www.betstars.uk/#/special_soccer/event/4236893', function(err,resp,body){
    if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200){
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $('marketselectionwrapper').each(function(){
          var nill = $(this).attr('em');
          price.push(nill);
        });
        console.log(price);
    }
});
```

I am assuming the problem lies with the ".attr('em');" but I cannot seem to find any help.
I found this link:
[Accessing the value of an "em" tag in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776358/accessing-the-value-of-an-em-tag-in-javascript)

The information I am trying to grab is the odds(19/4) for the 0-0 score as shown: [0-0 Score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTn7d.png)

But I struggled to get the information I needed from it. Any help would be great.

After help from Pavlo I've managed to get this:

```html
var request = require('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio')
    price = [];

request('https://www.betstars.uk/#/special_soccer/event/4236893', function(err,resp,body){
    if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200){
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $('.marketingselectionwrapper em').each(function(){
          var nill = $(this).text();
          price.push(nill);
        });
        console.log(price);
    }
});
```

Unfortunatly it's still not giving me any data as I am getting an empty array each time.  Sorry if the answer is super obvious!

Comment: `em` is a tag, not an attribute.  It would be helpful if you posted a sample of the html you're working with and explain what content inside it you're trying to capture.  Is there a reason you want with cheerio instead of jQuery?

Comment: I have updated with a screenshot of the information I am trying to extract. I am open to using JQuery if it makes what I am doing more efficient, cheerio was just one of the first solutions I found.

Comment: @SurrealDreams cheerio vs. jQuery is not in the scope of this question. Please don't confuse the newcomer.

Comment: @Pavlo is correct, ignore my question about Cheerio.

Comment: @SamWalker you should comment on my answer, rather than edit your question. You still need to fix the selector, `'.marketingselectionwrapper em'`. Try just `'em'` to get some result, then try to find a parent selector that fits. Also, there is a comma missing at the end of line two.

Comment: The site has changed so I'm voting to close this. It's possible that JS was adding the element dynamically after page load.